# MS SQL. Cascade Delete and triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Short question: "Trigger did not fire on DeliveryLine when I delete DeliveryHeader with cascade"

DETAILS:

I have a tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeliveryHeader](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DeliveryHeader] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([Id] ASC)
); 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeliveryLine](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryHeaderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DeliveryLine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (   [Id] ASC )
);
```

And foreign key cascade delete:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DeliveryLine]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DeliveryLine_DeliveryHeader] FOREIGN KEY([DeliveryHeaderId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DeliveryHeader] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Also I have a trigger on DeliveryLine

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_DeliveryLine_DeleteLog]   
    ON [dbo].[DeliveryLine]
    AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- some code    
END
```

But trigger did not fire on DeliveryLine when I delete DeliveryHeader

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[DeliveryHeader];
```

### Is some way to fire trigger with cascade delete ? I know only roundabout way:

1. Delete Cascade from foreign key.
   updated:
2. Write another trigger :

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_DeliveryHeader_DeleteLog]   
   ON [dbo].[DeliveryHeader]
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
   AS 
   BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       DELETE FROM [dbo].[DeliveryLine] WHERE [DeliveryHeaderId] IN (SELECT Id from deleted)
       DELETE FROM [dbo].[DeliveryHeader] WHERE [Id] IN (SELECT Id from deleted)
   END
   ```

Comment: I truly believe that cascading deletes are evil. Another way is to create a procedure to delete what you want, where you explicitly say what you want to delete.

Comment: Yes, I know. I use it very rare. An very carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.[DeliveryLine]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.[DeliveryLine]
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.[DeliveryHeader]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.[DeliveryHeader]
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.DeliveryHeader (
    Id INT /*IDENTITY(1,1)*/ PRIMARY KEY
)
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.DeliveryLine (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DeliveryHeaderId INT NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.DeliveryLine WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DeliveryLine_DeliveryHeader FOREIGN KEY(DeliveryHeaderId)
    REFERENCES dbo.DeliveryHeader(Id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_DeliveryLine_DeleteLog]   
    ON [dbo].[DeliveryLine]
    AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    PRINT 'all works!!!'

END
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.DeliveryHeader (Id) VALUES (0)
INSERT INTO dbo.DeliveryLine (DeliveryHeaderId) VALUES (0)
GO

DELETE FROM dbo.DeliveryHeader WHERE Id = 0 -- trigger fire only when data exists in both tables


INSERT INTO dbo.DeliveryHeader (Id) VALUES (1) -- trigger not fire
DELETE FROM dbo.DeliveryHeader WHERE Id = 1
```

Comment: And what? Can't you add two words?

Comment: Correct. Sorry, I have not really data in line. Thats why didn't work

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri, i prefer to answer concisely :)

Comment: @Devart, and I prefer to read what was wrong with OP`s code. You could just say 'Hey OP, it should work, check your data', instead of copy pasting word for word code from question and making it as an answer. Sorry, but Idownvote from me.